# I used the command (code. -r) in the cmd window, but what does -r mean? (vscode)

Tags: visual-studio-code

While watching the YouTube development video, I used the command (`code . -r`) in the cmd window in vscode. What is this function? vscode turned on, but what does `-r` mean?

Answer (score 1):

The help says:
`-r --reuse-window   Force to open a file or folder in an already opened window.`

Full help is available to you:

```
$ code -h
code 1.55.2

Usage: code [options][paths...]

To read from stdin, append '-' (e.g. 'ps aux | grep code | code -')

Options
  -d --diff <file> <file>           Compare two files with each other.
  -a --add <folder>                 Add folder(s) to the last active window.
  -g --goto <file:line[:character]> Open a file at the path on the specified line and character position.
  -n --new-window                   Force to open a new window.
  -r --reuse-window                 Force to open a file or folder in an already opened window.
  -w --wait                         Wait for the files to be closed before returning.
  --locale <locale>                 The locale to use (e.g. en-US or zh-TW).
  -h --help                         Print usage.

Extensions Management
  --list-extensions                                           List the installed extensions.
  --show-versions                                             Show versions of installed extensions, when using
                                                              --list-extensions.
  --category                                                  Filters installed extensions by provided category, when
                                                              using --list-extensions.
  --install-extension <extension-id[@version] | path-to-vsix> Installs or updates the extension. The identifier of an
                                                              extension is always `${publisher}.${name}`. Use
                                                              `--force` argument to update to latest version. To
                                                              install a specific version provide `@${version}`. For
                                                              example: 'vscode.csharp@1.2.3'.
  --uninstall-extension <extension-id>                        Uninstalls an extension.
  --enable-proposed-api <extension-id>                        Enables proposed API features for extensions. Can receive
                                                              one or more extension IDs to enable individually.

Troubleshooting
  -v --version                       Print version.
  --verbose                          Print verbose output (implies --wait).
  --log <level>                      Log level to use. Default is 'info'. Allowed values are 'critical', 'error',
                                     'warn', 'info', 'debug', 'trace', 'off'.
  -s --status                        Print process usage and diagnostics information.
  --prof-startup                     Run CPU profiler during startup
  --disable-extensions               Disable all installed extensions.
  --disable-extension <extension-id> Disable an extension.
  --sync <on> <off>                  Turn sync on or off
  --inspect-extensions <port>        Allow debugging and profiling of extensions. Check the developer tools for the
                                     connection URI.
  --inspect-brk-extensions <port>    Allow debugging and profiling of extensions with the extension host being paused
                                     after start. Check the developer tools for the connection URI.
  --disable-gpu                      Disable GPU hardware acceleration.
  --max-memory                       Max memory size for a window (in Mbytes).
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line):

> -r or --reuse-window  Forces opening a file or folder in the last active window.

IE, it doesn't launches a new instance of VSC, but opens a new tab in the existing opened instance, if it exists.

Comment: Thanks, official document.